# How to pass multiple associated files to a program?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-shell

I have written a Windows software and I have associated a file extension with this program. When I double click a data file then my program starts up and opens the file. So far it works. But when I select multiple files and then click "Open" in the context menu then multiple instances of my program are started, one instance for one file. I want Windows to open ALL files with a single instance of my program. Is this possible without implementing a one-instance-handler in my program?

Currently the `MyFileType/shell/open/command` in the registry looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

Maybe there is some special Token/Variable I have to use instead of the "%1" to get it working? On Linux I have to use %f for a single file and %F for a list of files. Is there something similar on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to associate your app with the default shell verb (e.g. “open,”  or “play,”) for the file type, and implements a drop target that uses SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject to get the selected files. Suggested reading: [How the Shell Invokes Verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969385.aspx#invoking_verbs)

If you don't like to take over the default verb, you can add your verb to the file association's [open with list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb166549%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Another method is to make your app a singleton and send the document's path to the first instance via inter-process communication methods such as DDE or RPC. This requires you to keep your main window responsive (for example, won't work if you are showing a dialog)

Comment: (Not enough space in these comments, so I split it into three): First paragraph: Dont' get it. I'm sorry, I'm not a Windows developer. My application is platform-independent and written in Java. It is just an EXE file which opens all files which were specified as command line arguments. No idea what SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObjet is and how I could do this in Java. And as far as I know I already use a default shell verb ("open" in this case).

Comment: Second paragraph: I tried this OpenWithList but it doesn't work and the documentation says this is for registering multiple applications for the same file type. That's not what I need. I already associated my application with the file type and it works. I just don't want Windows to open my application multiple times when I open a list of files in one go.

Comment: Third paragraph: In my question I wrote that I want to avoid this hassle but if Windows is really not able to pass a list of files to a program then I have to do it like this.

Comment: If you are going to call Windows's shell API, you need to use native interface such as JNI or your own native shim program written in other language that has easier access to Windows API. If you want to keep the selection order, I don't think there is a platform-independent way. If you do not need to maintain the order, you can make your app singleton and use named pipe to send the file name to the first instance in your additional instances, then exit without opening the file from the command line.

Comment: Looks like no better idea pops up. So I solved the problem by running my application as a singleton and using inter-process communication to pass the command-line-arguments from secondary instances to the first instance. As suggested by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

%* might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. It is empty. And when I use "%*" (With quotes) then the program tries to open a file with an empty filename.